# Set up a SWIFT project with git (and connect it to Github)

Tags: xcode, swift, git, github, gitignore

how do I correctly set up a SWIFT based project when I want to use Xcode, SWIFT and git and hook up the project with the Github repository.

What with and in what order I need to start? In what step do I need to add .gitignore (before I create a project in Xcode or after?) etc.?

Comment: This is a very broad question hence flagging it as such. Also this is a very basic question you can get help on almost everywhere on internet if you could only bother to visit google.com.

Comment: Yes, you are maybe right: this is kind of simple question..: let me please re-ask: Shell I start creating a Xcode project with git support and then add .gitignore AND then use untrack/track all files as instructed in this [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository?rq=1) or should I create a folder, put .gitignore file there, init git and then somehow create an Xcode  project ? Is order important here? PS: I have been googling too, happened ended up with "no" answer to this. Thanks!

Comment: Create a project, add it to git rep, then perform whatever actions you want with it. I am not aware of gitignore so I can't help you there. If you want to ignore some files from tracking, just don't add them to rep.

Comment: The same way u always do with git, git doesnt care what data it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a github repo and clone it to your local machine. 
Then dump you project in it. 
Then do a git add, commit and push to the remote github repo.

Here's a [git cheat](https://training.github.com/kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf) sheet by github